# Finding maximum size of range in a sorted integer array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am looking for an implementation in JavaScript  for the following problem.

Consider a sorted array:

```
[1,2,5,9,10,12,20,21,22,23,24,26,27]
```

I would like to calculate the length of the maximum range that increased by 1, duplicates are not allowed.

The given example has the following ranges:

```
1,2
9,10
20,21,22,23,24 // the maximum range
26,27
```

So the return value for the given example should be 5.

I know how to solve this problem with the obvious solution, but I believe it is possible to solve the problem  with more efficient and short algorithm.

Comment: So. What is the "obvious" solution?

Comment: Iteration through the array and comparing between the ranges sizes.  But I have a lot of assumptions, so maybe there are better solutions.

Comment: @AlexLavriv It is O(n) problem. If your solution is `O(n)` then i don't think it can be more efficient.

Comment: Are duplicates in the array allowed?

Comment: Duplicates are not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A short solution

I don't think this is any more efficient than what pretty much everybody else has suggested, but the code is reasonably short and only loops over the array once, except for the first element. Not sure if it's any help:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 5, 9, 10, 12, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27];
var streak = 0, best = 0, bestStart;
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i]-arr[i-1] === 1) streak++;
  else streak = 0;
  if (streak > best) [best, bestStart] = [streak, i - streak];
}
var bestArr = arr.slice(bestStart, bestStart + best + 1);
console.log('Best streak: '+bestArr);
```

### Speeding it up

After looking at the code, I realized that there is a way to speed it up slightly, by not checking the last few elements of the array, based on the previous value of `best`:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 5, 9, 10, 12, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27];
var streak = 0, best = 0, bestStart;
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(best > arr.length - i + streak) break;
  if(arr[i]-arr[i-1] === 1) streak++;
  else streak = 0;
  if (streak > best) [best, bestStart] = [streak, i - streak];
}
var bestArr = arr.slice(bestStart, bestStart + best + 1);
console.log('Best streak: '+bestArr);
```

Comment: @PhilippMaurer great idea, I didn't think of that to be honest. I'll update my answer right away.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to iterate the array, keeping the the current range as long as the numbers are successors. If the next number is not a successor of the previous number, close the current range and store its length - by comparing it to the length of the last range.

In this approach, the array is iterated only once and the maximum found length of a range is updated in constant time, yielding an `O(n)` algorithm where `n` is the number of elements in the input.

An implementation in C#-like pseudocode could be as follows.

```
int MaximumLength = minus infinity
int CurrentValue = Input[0];
int CurrentLength = 1;

for(int i = 1; i < Input.Length; i++)
{
    if ( CurrentValue + 1 == Input[i] )
    {
        // same range
        CurrentLength = CurrentLength + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // new range
        MaximumLength = Math.Max(MaximumLength, CurrentLength);
        CurrentLength = 1;
    }
    CurrentValue = Input[i];
}
// check current length again after loop termination
MaximumLength = Math.Max(MaximumLength, CurrentLength);
```

It is impossible to obtain better than `O(n)` because the input cannot be read in less than `O(n)` time. If that would be possible, it would imply that there are instances for which the result does not depend on every element of the input, which is not the case for the given problem. The algorithm Philipp Maurer has sketched below would also yield an `O(n)` runtime bound if the maximum range length is 1, i.e. no adjacent numbers in the input are successors.

Comment: Its not possible to do it under `O(n)` i think.  
An improvement could be to increase the step size to the size of current found range and see if the difference of the fields are the same as the range, meaning that those can be direct successors. If they are the fields inbetween have to be checked for duplicates, otherwise they can be skipped.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer This is a misunderstanding; I didn't mean to stop the discussion by any means; however, apparently the runtime bound (in the sense of Big-Oh-notation) cannot be improved. This does of course not mean that other improvements are possible.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I deleted my comment

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should find the maximum length first and not last.

```
Let max = 0
Let n = array length
While n > 2
  Let m = 0
  While m <= (array length - n)
    Let first = m
    Let last = m + n - 1 
    Let diff = (value of element 'last' in array) - (value of element 'first' in array)
    if diff = n - 1 then
      max = n
      stop
    end if
    Increase m
  end while
  Decrease n
end while
```

**Edit (javascript implementation)**

```
var a = [1,2,5,9,10,12,20,21,22,23,24,26,27];
var max = 1;
var n = a.length;
while(n > 2) {
  var m = 0;
  while(m <= a.length - n)
  {
    var first = m;
    var last = m + n - 1;
    var diff = a[last] - a[first];
    if (diff == n - 1 && diff > max) {
      max = n;
      break;
    }
    m++;
    }
  n--;
}

console.log(max);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mz1ny4oz/)

Comment: Anyway your algorithm seems to be in the class `O(n²)` for the worst case and therefore be slower than the original algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, i oversaw the inner `while` condition. Deleted my comments

Answer (score 0):

I think looping and comparing with stored previous maximum length is optimal solution. Maybe like this:

```js
function findLongestRange(input) {
  let maxLength = 0
  let currentLength = 0

  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (i !== input.length) {
      if (input[i] === input[i + 1] - 1) {
        currentLength++
      } else {
        if (maxLength <= currentLength && currentLength !== 0) {
          maxLength = currentLength + 1
        }
        currentLength = 0
      }
    }
  }

  return maxLength
}

const data = [1, 2, 5, 9, 10, 12, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27]
console.log(findLongestRange(data))
```

Here is the version with tests to check how it works with different input.

```js
const data = [1, 2, 5, 9, 10, 12, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27]

function findLongestRange(input) {
  let maxLength = 0
  let currentLength = 0

  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (i !== input.length) {
      if (input[i] === input[i + 1] - 1) {
        currentLength++
      } else {
        if (maxLength <= currentLength && currentLength !== 0) {
          maxLength = currentLength + 1
        }
        currentLength = 0
      }
    }
  }

  return maxLength
}

console.clear()
;[
  [[1,2,5,6,7,1,2], 3],
  [[], 0],
  [data, 5],
  [[1,2,3], 3],
  [[1,3,4,6,8,1], 2],
  [[1,3,5], 0],
].forEach((test, index) => {
  const result = findLongestRange(test[0])
  console.assert(result === test[1], `Fail #${index}: Exp: ${test[1]}, got ${result}`)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

A Python answer:

```
l = [1,2,5,9,10,12,20,21,22,23,24,26,27]
current_range = None
current_range_val = 0
max_range = 0
max_range_val = 0
for i, j in zip(l, l[1:]):
    if j - i == 1:
        current_range_val += 1
        if current_range is None:
            current_range = (i, j)
        current_range = (current_range[0], j)
    else:
        if current_range_val > max_range_val:
            max_range = current_range
            max_range_val = current_range_val
        current_range_val = 0
        current_range = (j, None)

print(max_range)
```

gives

```
(20, 24)
```